# Singularity container never has python in it?

Tags: python, docker, containers, singularity-container

I have to use singularity to package my code to run on a school server.

I have tried to build a basic container from just the python3.6-slim image, and then also installed python in the `%post` section for good measure.

I tried some other bases, too, like debian buster and ubuntu 20.04.

Currently the definition file looks like this:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:20.04

%post
    # Downloads the latest package lists (important).
    apt-get update -y
    # Runs apt-get while ensuring that there are no user prompts that would
    # cause the build process to hang.
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python3.6
```

Every time, after the image builds, I try to run `python --version` and it just keeps insisting: `python: not found`

I feel like I am missing something obvious in the documentation, but can't figure out what it is that I am missing. How does a container built on the official Python docker image... not have python installed?

Comment: `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3.6` should be `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following definition file:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:20.04

%post
    apt-get update 
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3
    apt-get -y clean
    rm -rf rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and then run the following commands in the shell:

```
sudo singularity build ubuntu-python.sif ubuntu-python.def
singularity run ubuntu-python.sif
```

and in the container (with the result added below command):

```
Singularity> python3 -V
Python 3.8.2
```

Comnparing my working example to yours I see several issues:

- you run `apt-get update` twice - once is enough
- you try to install package python3.6 - Ubuntu is a Debian-based distribution, and like Debian only has single `python3` package rather than separate packages for every Python 3 version
- you run `python --version` instead of `python3 --version` - in Ubuntu `python` is an alias for `python2`, more about that can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3) and [here](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

You also mention image `python3.6-slim` - there is no such Docker image (I'm assuming you're talking about Docker image, since you're using Docker Ubuntu image later). There is, however, `python:3.6-slim` image. Here is my quick test of using it with Singularity:

```
singularity shell docker://python:3.6-slim
Singularity> python --version
Python 3.6.12
Singularity> python3 --version
Python 3.6.12
```

Note: I use `singularity run` with Ubuntu-based image, because its default command is `bash`. With `python:3.6-slim` I have to use `singularity shell` as its default command starts interactive Python shell.

Edit: You should **never** install Python manually if you're using an image that already has Python installed - you'll most likely end with two versions of Python 3 in the same container, which will cause hard to debug problems.